# Explanation for でもしたら vs したら

Tags: grammar

Whats the difference between

食べたら〜
and
食べてでもしたら〜

Comment: Isn't 食べてでもしたら a typo for 食べでもしたら?

Answer (score 2):

The conditional たら is used neutrally, while the でもしたら expresses a condition you feel against and hope doesn't come true. I think adding "heaven forbid" or "perish the thought" may be a good analogue in English. Compare:

> 私のプリンを食べたら、めちゃくちゃ怒るからね。
>   "If you eat my custard pudding, I'm going to be really mad. (So be warned.)"

vs

> 私のプリンを食べでもしたら、めちゃくちゃ怒るからね。
>   "If, heaven forbid, you eat my custard pudding, I'm going to be really mad. (So be warned.)"