# Understanding the でも in 「突っ切る時に万が一子供を轢きでもしたら大変である。」

Tags: particle-でも

Consider

> でも突っ切る時に万が一子供を轢き**でもしたら**大変である。
>
> But, if by chance when I break across, it would be awful if I were to run over a kid.

I'm trying to understand what the でも means in でもしたら. The author earlier states:

> **でもしたら** or でもしようものなら--"(even) if you were". **This pattern attaches to the 連用形 of a verb.**

I'm assuming the でも is *not* the conjunction particle ("but"), but rather でも = ((the て-form of だ) + も)? So a slightly more literal translation becomes something like:

> But *even* (でも) by chance running over a kid, if it would be done (したら), would be bad.

Is this the case?

Then, this "is-even" (でも) is used to convey a [sense of hoping that something doesn't come true](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48176/explanation-for-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89-vs-%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%82%89):

> The conditional たら is used neutrally, while the でもしたら expresses a condition you feel against and hope doesn't come true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This でも is neither a conjunctive nor `で + も`, but a particle meaning "～ or something".

- [Meaning of "でも" in "食事でもどうですか？"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/5010)
- [The use of でも and ででも in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13463/5010)
- [でも and other particles: conjunction, exclusion, and word order](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94470/5010)

轢きでもしたら is 轢いたら with でも added. If you know [how to attach a contrastive-wa (or も, すら, etc) to a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21075/5010), this follows the same pattern of `連用形 + particle + する`.

Comment: Is the でも in 「便せんがなかったらないで、**コピー用紙でも**かまいません」 another example of this usage? Rough, semi-literal translation: "If you don't have stationery, then you don't have it; either way, copy paper **(or something like that)** isn't an inconvenience."

Comment: @George No, it's `で (with/by) + も (also/even/too)`. "I'm fine with copy paper, too".